# Makefile not rebuilding dependencies

Tags: makefile

I'm new to using makefiles and trying to produce a basic makefile as part of an exercise for university. I have two source code files, chello.c and writeexit.s, which have to be compiled/assembled and then linked to produce chello.

This is the code I have so far for the makefile:

```
chello: chello.o  writeexit.o
  ld -N chello.o writeexit.o -o chello

chello.o: chello.c
  gcc -c chello.c -o chello.o

writeexit.o: writeexit.s
  as writeexit.s -o writeexit.o
```

The whitespace before ld, gcc and as are all tabs, so I think the whitespacing is fine. When I call 'make makefile', it returns 'make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'.' However, if I change the dependencies of chello, like chello.c, the same message is returned and chello's behaviour is not modified.

Comment: How are you invoking `make`?  It sounds like you might be typing `make makefile`, whereas you should be typing either `make -f makefile` or (unless you also have a file called `Makefile` lurking around in the same directory), just `make`.

Answer (score 2):

From `man make`:

> make  executes  commands in the makefile to update one or more target
>   names, where name is typically a program.  If no -f option is present,
>   make will look for the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile,
>   in that order.

`make makefile` will actually execute your "makefile" (because it is listed among the default names in the man page) file, trying to build the "makefile" target (because of the argument you are passing), which already exists

What you need is to build the "chello" binary, so you have to type:

`make chello`

Or alternatively:

`make -f makefile chello`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative account here, it seems to work fine if I just call "make" instead of "make makefile". This question can be ignored.

Comment: Just to add to this, if no target is specified when invoking make it will build the first target listed in the file. Because of this most Makefile's will have "all" as the first target listed.